# Detecting very simple movements (a hand waving) usable on 8bits microcontroller

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, movement

Recently i saw a video about Nest Protect, an smart smoke detector, that can be operated by [waving your hand](http://youtu.be/QXp-LYBXwfo?t=35s) under it. Since there is no visible holes on the lower part i suppose they are not using any light/acoustic sensors, like IR or ultrasonic, so it could be an RF type sensor, but i have no idea what specific sensor, do you know how they detect the waving of the hand with such a precision?, i mean, i can easily detect movement with a PIR sensor, but i have no idea how to reduce the range (if possible) in order to detect only near objects movements.

**EDIT:** I found this picture of the sensor, they are actually two, one vertical and the other one inclined, seeing the picture can you tell what sensor type is?

[image]

Comment: Look like US (Utra Sone == high frequency sound) to me.

Comment: but they are behind the plastic enclosure, do they still work?

Comment: Dunno. Or maybe the twins are just beepers, and that bigger thingy with 'FAST' on it is the handwaving detector.

Comment: Not gonna read past the sloppy writing.

Comment: Teardown says ultrasound: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nest-protect-teardown. And not an 8-bit micro but *three* 32-bit ARM-based devices.

Answer (score 1):

Those two are definitely ultrasonic transducers. One for Tx one for Rx. My guess is that only a hand wave close enough (because of the tilt angle) will trigger this. It could detect a simple echo, or might even do a doppler analysis to detect movements. More advanced method would be to use a "chirp" signal, but I doubt that is required here.